# How to add <textarea> before button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textarea

I have a simple list of "News Articles" that I would like to be available for commentary. I've created an "Add Comment" button.

I want the button to create a `<form>` with a `<textarea>` immediately before the clicked button AND also create a "Cancel" button immediately after the clicked button. (I figured this out while posing this question)

The only thing that remains is that I would like the "Cancel" button to delete the newly created `<textarea>` and itself upon click. AND for extra credit, how do I prevent the "Add Comment" button from making more than one blank "textareas"?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".AddComment").click(function () {
     $("<form><textarea name='ResearchUpdate' placeholder='Enter your comment here' rows='3' cols='40' class='Commentary'></textarea> </form>").insertBefore(this);
     $("<button class='CancelComment'>Cancel</button>").insertAfter(this);
 });
 
 $(".CancelComment").click(function (){
  $(this).prev(".Commentary").remove();
  $(this).remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>News Entries</title>

</head>
<body>

<h2><a href="#">Killer Rabbit On The Loose</a></h2>
<p>Date: 01/23/2015</p>
<p>Author: Bobert</p>
<p>Subject: Animals</p>
<p>Most Recent Comment: None Yet.</p>
<button class="AddComment">Add Comment</button>

<h2><a href="#">Porsche Unveils Ultra Fast Minivan</a></h2>
<p>Date:02/14/2015</p>
<p>Author: Jimmy</p>
<p>Subject: Cars</p>
<p>Most Recent Comment:</p>
<p>This is genius on Porsche's behalf! I can drop off the kids at school, go grocery shopping and still have time to go racing with my buddies. All without worrying that my emissions aren't falsified and polluting the world.  --SemiProRacer997</p>
<button class="AddComment">Add Comment</button>


<h2> <a href="#">Apple Releases iPhone Inifity</a></h2>
<p>Date:03/11/2015</p>
<p>Author: Frank</p>
<p>Subject: Technology</p>
<p>Most Recent Comment:</p>

<button class="AddComment">Add Comment</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.AddComment').one('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var bt=$(this);
        var el=$('<textarea name="comment" />');
        el.insertBefore(this);
        bt.text('Send comment').on('click',function(e){
            if (el.val().length==0){
                alert("Please fill the comment before send.");
                el.focus(); //Delete this row if you don't want user to focus on the textarea.
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({   
                type: 'POST',
                data : el,
                cache: false,  
                url: 'postUrl.php',
                success: function(data){
                    bt.after($('<b>Comment sent</b>').hide().fadeIn());
                    bt.add(el).hide();

                }   
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Use **one** to create the textarea (onetime), and than bind the submit event.

Comment: I'm trying to build on your suggestion, because ultimately I want to submit this information via ajax. How do I make sure multiple textareas aren't created and finally how do I run the ajax when there is text in the textarea?

Comment: I've used ONE in the code, to prevent multiple textarea creation.
The ajax call is already in the code, just change 'postUrl.php' with the url you need to receive the data.

Comment: Sorry for the lot of comments wizkid, I had some problem with the new lines on stack overflow comments area. At the end I edited the answer, so you can see the code that prevent any empty comments. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to show and hide already existing items, than creating on the fly and inserting them.

> Extra credit for not making Add Comment more than one textarea:

```
$(".AddComment").click(function () {
    $("<form><textarea name='ResearchUpdate' placeholder='Enter your comment here' rows='3' cols='40' class='Commentary'></textarea> </form>").insertBefore(this);
    $("<button class='CancelComment'>Cancel</button>").insertAfter(this);
    // Remove the click event and disable the button.
    $(this).off("click").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

**My proposed solution:**

Make sure you load the the comment box with every post with a class `.comment-box` and a `style="display: none;"` and use the following event handler.

```
$(".AddComment").click(function () {
  $(this).prev(".comment-box").toggle();
});
```

Also, you can have the `cancel` button to have the following event handler:

```
$(".cancel").click(function () {
  $(this).closest(".AddComment").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to wrap every post items in a container div with a css class which we can use for jQuery selection later.

```
<div class="postItem">
  <h2><a href="#">Killer Rabbit On The Loose</a></h2>
  <p>Date: 01/23/2015</p>
  <p>Author: Bobert</p>    
  <button class="AddComment">Add Comment</button>
</div>

<div class="postItem">
  <h2><a href="#">Second post</a></h2>
  <p>Date: 01/23/2015</p>
  <p>Author: Shyju</p>    
  <button class="AddComment">Add Comment</button>
</div>
```

And in your cancel button click event, get the container div, find the form and the cancel button and remove it,

```
$(document).on("click",".CancelComment",function (e){

    var _this = $(this);
    _this.closest(".postItem").find("form").remove();
    _this.remove();       

});
```

Working sample [here](http://jsbin.com/yuripet/edit?html,js,console,output)

You need to use jQuery `on` method  to bind the click event on the cancel button as they are dynamically created by your code and injected to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the form there already but have it hidden so that when you click the button it appears.  You can then disable the button using `$('#buttonId').prop('disabled', true);`

This will prevent any further clicks although the click wouldn't matter this way anyway as you only have one form to show so it wouldn't pop up any more.

Clicking the cancel button should fire a function that removes the content of the textarea in question, hides the form/textarea and re-enables the comment button

show_comment :

```
function show_comment(){<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$('#formId').show();<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$('#cancelButton').show();<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$('#commentButton').prop('disabled', true)<br>
}
```

remove_comment:

```
function remove_comment(){<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$('#textareaId').html('');<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$('#commentButton').prop('disabled', false);<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$('#cancelButton').hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues in your code.

1. You are adding click function for cancel button that does not exist on page load. You will have to add click after you add cancel button
2. You are doing prev() on cancel button which is wrong. The prev sibling of cancel button is add comment button and not text area.

Please see if following code fixes your issue.
I am also disabling add button once comment text area is added so that you dont add more text areas

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".AddComment").click(function () {
            var $addCommentBtn = $(this), 
                $commentTextArea;
            $addCommentBtn.prop( "disabled", true );
     $commentTextArea = $("<form><textarea name='ResearchUpdate' placeholder='Enter your comment here' rows='3' cols='40' class='Commentary'></textarea> </form>").insertBefore(this);
     $("<button class='CancelComment'>Cancel</button>").insertAfter(this).click(function (){
  $commentTextArea.remove();
  $(this).remove();
                $addCommentBtn.prop( "disabled", false );
     });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>News Entries</title>

</head>
<body>

<h2><a href="#">Killer Rabbit On The Loose</a></h2>
<p>Date: 01/23/2015</p>
<p>Author: Bobert</p>
<p>Subject: Animals</p>
<p>Most Recent Comment: None Yet.</p>
<button class="AddComment">Add Comment</button>

<h2><a href="#">Porsche Unveils Ultra Fast Minivan</a></h2>
<p>Date:02/14/2015</p>
<p>Author: Jimmy</p>
<p>Subject: Cars</p>
<p>Most Recent Comment:</p>
<p>This is genius on Porsche's behalf! I can drop off the kids at school, go grocery shopping and still have time to go racing with my buddies. All without worrying that my emissions aren't falsified and polluting the world.  --SemiProRacer997</p>
<button class="AddComment">Add Comment</button>


<h2> <a href="#">Apple Releases iPhone Inifity</a></h2>
<p>Date:03/11/2015</p>
<p>Author: Frank</p>
<p>Subject: Technology</p>
<p>Most Recent Comment:</p>

<button class="AddComment">Add Comment</button>


</body>
</html>
```